# Jquery and memory leaks in IE8

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

I have a library which binds events to input fields based on their class.  I've noticed memory usage in IE keeps creeping up as I navigate around the intranet, and this doesn't get freed up until I close the browser.

Do I need to do anything to clear these events from the input fields when the page closes to allow 'garbage collection'?

Thanks.

```
        $("input.PartNo" ).addClass("font8_input").attr({maxlength: '20',size:'20'})
        .bind('focus',function(event){javascript:fncAjaxClear();$(this).addClass("input_focus");})
        .bind('blur',function(event){if (typeof fncPartBlur === "function") fncPartBlur(''+$(this).attr("id")+'');$(this).removeClass("input_focus input_error");})
        .bind('keyup',function(event){javascript:fncAjaxSearch('wsDatabase','..\\AjaxBrowses\\PartBrowse.asp',''+$(this).attr("id")+'',''+$(this).attr("id")+'List','fncPreAjaxPart','fncPostAjaxPart');})
        .each(function(){$(this).after('<div id="'+$(this).attr("id")+'List" class="AjaxSuggest"></div>');});
```

There are multiple lines like this detecting a variety of input fields by class.
It adds a class, size, length, binds some events and also adds a div, which is used in the keyup function to output the list of results from the query to the DB.

Comment: I think you definitely do not need to implement feature that browser should have.

Comment: No. Garbage collection will happen automatically. Likely the memory footprint is coming from other things (history, cookies, etc). But, maybe show us some code you think might be the culprit as it isn't out of the question.

Comment: Indeed, it grows as you collect history behind you in navigation. GC is a feature in the browser, so you don't need to handle it.

Comment: In the 'Learning Jquery' third edition, it states about memory leakage and IE....

Comment: IE has a history of memory leaks, but usually within the page it is contained to until you reload the page. Once you reload, the garbage collector collects everything. Or is supposed to. But that wouldn't be something you could handle very easily.